# Is protobuf-net inefficient if I have a base classes annotated to include about a hundred derived types? Then 1000s of instances to be saved?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

My game is a city builder. On the last game we used BinaryFormatter to serialize our save data. That was nice and flexible, and never complained about all the weird ways I decided to format our save data.

Because of the dangers of BinaryFormatter, I've decided to find a replacement and I'm looking at protobuf-net.

In my game, all the important classes have a Serializable sub class that is responsible for Packing up and Unpacking the parent.

It looks something like this, always this pattern of parent game class T and packaging subclass TS.

```
[Serializable] 
public abstract class SaveClass<T, TS>{ 
     public abstract TS Pack(T obj); 
     public abstract T Unpack(T obj); 
}
```

And here's an example implementation:

```
[System.Serializable] 
public class EditTerrainJobsSaveData : Job.JobSaveData<EditTerrainJobs, EditTerrainJobsSaveData> 
{ 
    [NonSerialized] public EditTerrainProject ProjectRef_Injected; 
    public Status status; 
    public int currMoveUnitId; 

    public override EditTerrainJobsSaveData Pack(EditTerrainJobs j) 
    { 
        status = j.status; 
        currMoveUnitId = -1; 
        if(j.moveUnit != null) 
            currMoveUnitId = j.moveUnit.sortedIndexOrder; 
        return base.Pack(j); 
    } 

    public override EditTerrainJobs Unpack(EditTerrainJobs j) 
    { 
        base.Unpack(j); 

        j.status = status; 
        j.project = ProjectRef_Injected; 
        if(currMoveUnitId != -1) 
            j.moveUnit = ProjectRef_Injected.GetMoveUnit(currMoveUnitId); 
        return j; 
    } 
}
```

Somewhere else, where I'm packing up all the jobs. I'm storing them in a `List<object>` (which I know won't play nice with protobuf-net) and serializing that. That's all the background.

`List<object>` was fine for me because I was using reflection to understand how to unpack. But assuming I change it to some type that's a better fit. Like, and only guessing here so we can move on, `List<SaveClass<,> >`.

I'd have to decorate the SaveClass with a hundred different parent, subclass combinations. Not ideal. But what I really want to know after all this is if a type like SaveClass is decorated with hundreds of ProtoIncludes, assuming 10,000 saved instances does that balloon the final binary output? Or is that just to inform the serializer?